# Validation Tooltip on TextBox becomes orphaned when changing tabs

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, tooltip, controltemplate

I have a TextBox on a TabItem inside of a TabControl. Using INotifyDataError changed based validation, when there is an error in the TextBox and you focus on the TextBox a validation tooltip displays. If I navigate to a different tab, the Tooltip stays where it was even though I am on the new tab. Essentially creating an orphaned ToolTip. When I go back to the original tab with my textbox that has the validation error, I can create as many new orphaned validation tooltips by focusing on the textbox and switching tabs.

Using Silverlight Spy I've been trying to re-produce the visual tree. The TextBox is inside of a ScrollViewer inside of a Grid on a set of nested tab controls. Unfortunately, in my isolated sandbox I am as of yet unable to reproduce the issue. Meaning, the tooltip goes away when switching tabs.

Has anybody else ever encountered something like this?