# Remaining validation tooltip on TabControl

Tags: validation, tooltip, tabcontrol, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I have a problem with a `TabControl`, a `TextBox` and a validation `ToolTip`.

Imagine having a TabControl with two TabItems. On the first item there is a simple `TextBox`. This `TextBox` `Text` property is bound to a string property of the `UserControl` itself with `Mode=TwoWay` and `ValidatesOnExceptions=True`. The setter of that `Text` property throws an exception whenever something is set.

The `Resources` section of the `UserControl` contains a new default style for the `TextBox` and the validation `ToolTip` (those styles and templates however are taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

Now enter something into the `TextBox` and let the validation `ToolTip` appear:

[image]

Then change to the second tab. The validation ToolTip remains:

[image]

I have produced a VS solution containing a Silverlight application that demonstrates the issue. The VS solution zip archive is available [here](http://spontifixus.de/silverlight.net/645107/OrphanedValidationTooltip.zip).

Has anyone had similar problems or even a solution for that issue?

Disclaimer: There is similar question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347891/validation-tooltip-on-textbox-becomes-orphaned-when-changing-tabs) with regard to Silverlight 4 which has been unanswered since about one and a half years.
I already posted that question on [silverlight.net](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/258384/645261.aspx/) but got no replies for several days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug of the `TabControl`-implementation. I've implemented the this behavior to fix this in our application:

```cs
public class TabControlFixBehavior: Behavior<TabControl>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged;

        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var oldTabItem = args.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem;
            if (oldTabItem != null)
            {
                var popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups();
                foreach (var popup in popups)
                {
                    var toolTip = popup.Child as ToolTip;
                    if (toolTip != null)
                    {
                        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetRoot(toolTip.PlacementTarget) == oldTabItem.Content)
                        {
                            popup.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the validation tooltip is an implicit feature in silverlight 5.
Please clear the "UserControl.Resources" node in your "main page" usercontrol and you will have the expected behavior.

[EDIT] I did not read the end of your question, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, removing the resources indeed solves the issue, but is not an option in my case because I need these controls styled. I just included the default style from the MSDN in my example to prove that this problem is not being caused by my styles.